# SharedPreferences, gets the value in debug mode but not in run mode

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am testing an app. Login twitter and and then logout.
When logout, logout method runs(inside Settings/Options menu of MainActivity), and i clear sharedPreferences and return to loginActivity.

In loginActivity(onCreate), with putBoolean, i set the boolean value as true.
From loginActivity, with a botton click i go to MainActivity. In mainActivity, i get the value as false(the default value).
But, when I debug my app line by line, my sharedPreferences.getBoolean("xxx",false) method returns true.

I guess code is running so fast and blocking I/O causes sharedPreferences not to be able to get the true value in LoginActivity.

*See code blocks below, if needed:*

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Initialize application preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NAME, 0);

    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // ...

            isLoggedIn = true;

            // Save tokens and user info
            saveTwitterInfoSharedPref(session,isLoggedIn);

            goToMainActivity(consumerKey,consumerSecret);

        }


     private void saveTwitterInfoSharedPref(TwitterSession session, boolean isLoggedIn) {

     long userID = session.getUserId();

    /* Storing oAuth tokens to shared preferences */
    final Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();        
    e.putBoolean(Constants.TWITTER_LOGIN_STATUS, isLoggedIn);

    // Get UsersService via TwitterApiClient to get User object
    MyTwitterApiClient myTwitterApiClient = new MyTwitterApiClient(session);
    Call<User> user = myTwitterApiClient.getUsersService().show(userID, null, true);

        user.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> result) {
                String userProfileImgURL = result.data.profileImageUrlHttps;
                e.putString(Constants.PREF_USER_PROFILE_IMG_URL,userProfileImgURL);
                e.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

            }
        });
```

In MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case  R.id.itemMenuSignOut :
            SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NAME, 0);
            TwitterLogOut logOut = new TwitterLogOut();
            logOut.logoutTwitter(getApplicationContext(),mSharedPreferences);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
            this.finish();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

TwitterLogOut.class :

```
 public class TwitterLogOut {

    public void logoutTwitter(Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
      TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        if (twitterSession != null) {
           Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
           Twitter.logOut();
           ClearSharedPref(sharedPreferences);
    }
}

  public static void ClearSharedPref(SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences){
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
     editor.clear();
     editor.commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call commit, to be sure your changes to SharedPref are there. In your case you are putting the boolean flag and starting async task, and after the task is finished you commit your changes

Comment: Yeah X3Btel, that's right. I put all Editor methods and goToMainActivity(,)  inside async task which fixed it. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should move this line :

```
  goToMainActivity(consumerKey,consumerSecret);
```

into the `success` method in `saveTwitterInfoSharedPref`, like this :

```
user.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<User> result) {
            String userProfileImgURL = result.data.profileImageUrlHttps;
            e.putString(Constants.PREF_USER_PROFILE_IMG_URL,userProfileImgURL);
            e.commit();
            goToMainActivity(consumerKey,consumerSecret);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // DO something here, like warn the user with a toast
        }
    });
```

That way, you can be sure that the login was succesful, and that the preference has been saved BEFORE going to MainActivity.

Comment: Good caught! That fixed it. Thank you Orabig!